# Dividir um botão para alterar o background de parte dele

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Eu gostaria de fazer igual neste botão no caos, dividir para utilizar o 4 com o background cinza e o restante no branco comum, Obs. estou utilziando o botão do Bootstrap 4.
[image: Modelo do botão]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara isso tem na documentação... Se chama button-group https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/

Exemplo de aplicação

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Large button group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button> -->
                <input type="text" class="border px-2 border-right-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn border border-left-0">←</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```